# Locked out of Windows 10, forgot password

Tags: windows, windows-10, passwords, safe-mode

I have a **Windows 10 PC** and I changed the password the other day, but forgot it. It is running in **dual boot** with Ubuntu on the other side, the files are shared, it uses **“GRUB” interface** on boot to choose what OS I am booting into.

I do not have a password recovery USB (from what I read to make one you have to make one inside the OS you are setting up the USB for, which i cant do). My only other computer is a M1 MacBook that can run Windows 11 in Parallels. This is somewhat urgent as the majority of my school work is done on this computer.

This has really stumped me and I am not sure how to fix this, any help will be much appreciated. I am a tech nerd so please, use fancy words, I should understand them. Thanks in advance!

I am also not able to login via <kbd>F7</kbd> to get to safe mode for some reason.

Comment: Is this a Microsoft account, or a local only account? are you logging in to win11 on parallels using the same account? If it is a MS account you can reset that password as a Microsoft account.

Comment: @music2myear i am trying to login to a windows login page. It is asking for my password to my windows 10 OS. It is linked to a Microsoft account. Does that help

Comment: Then go to the Microsoft account site and regain account access there. There will probably also be a forgot password link or button right there on the login screen that'll help you work through this.